# DNOA OpenID+OAuth to Google from localhost and public site fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth, appharbor

I use DNOA for authentication + authorization with google in my website.

http://ugi-2.apphb.com/Authentication.htm

When I run on local host I get this error

```
return_to 'http://localhost:8976/Register/Login' not under realm 'http://anonymous/'.
```

from this piece of code:

```
 private void HandleAuthNullResponse(IAuthenticationResponse authResponse)
        {
            // Google requires that the realm and consumer key be equal,
            // so we constrain the realm to match the realm in the web.config file.
            // This does mean that the return_to URL must also fall under the key,
            // which means this sample will only work on a public web site
            // that is properly registered with Google.
            // We will customize the realm to use http or https based on what the
            // return_to URL will be (which will be this page).

            var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerHelper.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);

            //Realm realm = "http://localhost:8976/";
            Realm realm = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + consumer.ConsumerKey + "/";
            IAuthenticationRequest authReq = GoogleConsumerHelper.RelyingParty.CreateRequest(GoogleConsumerHelper.GoogleOPIdentifier, realm);
```

the error fits somehow what is commented  by DNOA

It was strange as I saw other code that works for localhost but is much less structured.

I then turned to google site and saw:

> Registering your web application
>
> There are three levels of registration:
>
> 1. Unregistered: Application is not recognized by Google. The Access
>      Request page, which prompts your users to either grant or deny access
>      for your application, displays this caution highlighted in yellow:
>      "This website has not registered with Google. We recommend that you
>      continue the process only if you trust this destination."
> 2. Registered: ...
> 3. Registered with enhanced security: ...
>
> Registration is optional but recommended. ...

I even tried to publish on appHarbor and that didn't help (don't have logs there yet)

How can I work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message your seeing is because the OpenID spec requires that the return_to URL be a derivative of the realm URL, and obviously in your case it isn't.  http://localhost/ doesn't fall anywhere under http://anonymous/.  If you set your realm to your site's actual root URL so that return_to is under it, this error should go away.

I'd be interested in seeing the documentation from Google that says it accepts a realm of http://anonymous/ and a return_to any something other than anonymous.

Comment: can you please donwload and run this project? http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/

Comment: @EladBenda I think you're confusing that library's use of ordinary OAuth 1.0 with this question's use of the OpenID+OAuth extension.  They are quite different scenarios, and while both DNOA and matlus' library can do anonymous OAuth with Google, neither library (I believe) can do anonymous OpenID+OAuth extension.